# Equal distribution for table rows - HTML AND CSS

Tags: html, html-table

I just made a table and I have three records that I'm trying to display. It successfully displays the information but it crams it all in one row. When I want it to display over three rows. I'm doing something obvious wrong but I still need some help. Here is my code:

### HTML

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
        <td><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", account_assignment_path(assignment), method: :delete %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

### Screen Shot:

[image]

As you can see they all try to fit in one column. How can I fix this so they spread  out?

Comment: Looks like OP is using Ruby Rails btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the templating language you're using, but this is likely due to not including the `<tr>` element in your loop.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
    <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", account_assignment_path(assignment), method: :delete %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```